# Datepart month shows last day of previous month SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been scratching my head a bit this morning as the resolution to this is probably very simple but when I run the following criteria I end up with the last day of January showing in the results.

```
DATEADD(SECOND, chg.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, '19700101') >= 
    DATEADD(DD, - (DATEPART(m, GETDATE())), CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DATE))
```

I just want results from February. Can someone point at my obvious mistake?

Thanks

Comment: First explain what you want to do and what this code is supposed to achieve. Why would you care about seconds since 1970??  And why would the *month* number* show any date? It's just a number between 1 and 12

Comment: It will bring last day of previous month. SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())

Comment: Yes please provide some expected results. Other question: Having the todays date; why do you subtract 2 days(..being in february) from todays date? It doesnt make sence and I cant see any reason why to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subtracting the *month number* from the current date. This doesn't return the last day of the previous month, it returns a date up to 12 days in the past. It's only an accident that *today*, February 2nd,  this returns January 31st.

If you want to find the beginning of the month, subtract the month day -1. After all you don't want 2018/2/0 :

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1-(DATEPART(day, GETDATE())), CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DATE))
```

Better yet, use DATEFROMPARTS :

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(GETDATEA()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
```

Using DATEFROMPARTS is easier to read and maintain, while making the same number of calls to GETDATE() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thankyou very much, that's exactly what I was after. Apologies, I'm fairly new to manipulating dates in SQL

Comment: @nixxrite T-SQL doesn't have great support for date or string manipulation. Try to avoid older tricks though and check the available functions: DATEFROMPARTS, EOMONTH, PARSE, FORMAT etc

Answer (score 0):

In order to get last day of preivous month use the code below

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to get the last day of the previous month though. I want to get all data from the current month. My code is pulling everything so far from February and the last day of January.

Comment: You can use where cluase e.g where datetime>'2018-02-01 00:00:00' and getdate()

Answer (score 0):

To get Last day of any month, Useful scripts from Pinal's Blog

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
LastDay_PreviousMonth

----Last Day of Current Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
LastDay_CurrentMonth

----Last Day of Next Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0))
```

Comment: The last day of any month is returned by EOMONTH(). There's no need for second arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

This should provide the first day of the current month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, -1 * CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE DAY(GETDATE())-1 END, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```